# Return the count of subcollection array with the result in MongoDB and sort with ascending

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having trouble in getting the count of a subcollection with the sorting of result in ascending order account to the count.

here is how my collection `scripts` looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393"),
    "label" : "Binarization",
    "name" : "nlbin",
    "require" : []
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbfb5eb14e5fc44d5e9c87"),
    "label" : "Binarization",
    "name" : "jpeg",
    "require" : [ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393")]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbfb4db14e5fc44d5e9c76"),
    "label" : "Binarization",
    "name" : "pseg",
    "require" : [ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393"), ObjectId("58bbfb5eb14e5fc44d5e9c87")]
}
```

So problem is i wanted to return the collections with the count of array field `require` also sort them  in ascending order. The query i wrote was something like this:

```
db.getCollection('scripts').aggregate({ $unwind: "$require" },{ $sortByCount:"$require" },{$sort: {count: 1}})
```

Problem is that it is not returning the desired result it actually returns me something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393"),
    "count" : 2
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbfb5eb14e5fc44d5e9c87"),
    "count" : 1
}
```

which is totally wrong as `ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393")` should have count `0`. Also the collection with the largest `count` (i.e. `ObjectId("58bbfb4db14e5fc44d5e9c76")`) is not even included in the result.

Final result should be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbf0a4b14e5fc44d5e9393"),
    "count" : 0
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbfb5eb14e5fc44d5e9c87"),
    "count" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bbfb4db14e5fc44d5e9c76"),
    "count" : 2
}
```

Hope you guys understood what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is add an extra field (using **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)**) that holds the `require` array size without the need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and then sort the documents based on that field, e.g.

```
db.getCollection('scripts').aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { "count": { "$size": "$require" } } },
    { "$sort": { "count": 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks its working. This is nice that i can make projection like fields in my aggregation function.